# What is the attribute to check if products are sold in incrememts?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, catalog, php-5.4, inventory

I have the below HTML that I need to wrap in a PHP IF Statement. I need the statement to check if **Enable Qty Increments = Yes** (set in Inventory settings of Magento) however, I'm not sure what the attribute to check is.

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('INSERT ATTRIBUTE HERE')=='Yes'): ?>
    <p>Only available in box quantities</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Buy as much as you want</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getQtyIncrements()): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Only available in box quantities');?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Buy as much as you want');?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yep that's the right answer. See my alternative answer also ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get this: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /location/filename.phtml" relating to the first line. Thoughts?

Comment: sorry, I forgot a closing bracket. Try again.

Comment: Nice one. I'm now left with this message, "Fatal error: Call to a member function getStockItem() on a non-object". Do I have to add another line similar to this (<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>) in order to make this work?

Comment: make the if statement this `$this->getProduct()->->getStockItem()->getQtyIncrements()`. But it really depends on where you are using this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Marius answer to only check if the field is set to Yes and not check the actual values:

```
<?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getEnableQtyIncrements(): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Only available in box quantities');?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Buy as much as you want');?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```